# How to start a spring-mvc application with gradle on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, gradle

Hi i am trying to find out how to initialize a spring mvc application on netebans.

When you create a new gradle project on netbeans is a java project, but how can i configure it to make it a spring mvc project.

Is there any tutorial out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty much on your own. You will need to configure Gradle to build your application. I assume it means using 'war' plugin and adding various Spring MVC dependencies. NetBeans with https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project plugin will then be able to understand Java related part.

There is a work in progress to add support for web application development to this plugin but nothing publicly available as far as I know.