# How to create a Spring project with Gradle in Netbeans

Tags: java, spring, gradle, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.2. I've downloaded the Gradle plugin. But when I want to create a project I can't seem to be able to pick both Spring and Gradle. I've tried importing Spring from `build.gradle` but it simply produces an error with the build file. I can't seem to integrate Gradle with Spring. How do I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a spring-mvc application with gradle on netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22958397/2985643).